# python string iterpolation on files with % as comment

Tags: python, fabric

I would like to use fabric to generate a custom ejabberd config file and upload to server. fabric uses python string interpolation in `fabric.contrib.files.upload_template`. Unfortunately  ejabberd config file uses

> %%%

for comments

Using python string interpolation throws an error on the following simplified example:

> %%% this is a comment
>
> {resurl, %(resturl)s}

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 't' (0x74) at index 4
```

I could replace every non uneven occurence of % > 1 with an even one. 
or do

```
val = re.sub("%", "??", open("ejabberd.cfg").read())
val = val % {"resturl": "http://localhost:500/"}    
val.replace("??", "%")
```

There might be a better solution to treat file's having %, maybe by telling python to use another character to mark the start of a specifier.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *double* each `%`:

```
%%%%%% this is a comment

{resurl, %(resturl)s}
```

This escapes the `%`; the output transforms each `%%` back to `%`.

Demo:

```
>>> val = '''\
... %%%%%% this is a comment
... 
... {resurl, %(resturl)s}
... '''
>>> print val % {"resturl": "http://localhost:500/"}    
%%% this is a comment

{resurl, http://localhost:500/}
```